# Can we stop persisting [datapersistance]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [datapersistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datapersistance) tag is a spelling error.  The 75 questions tagged as such should probably be tagged [data-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-persistence) instead.

Comment: On the same subject, can we fix [tag:polyglot-persistance] too?

Comment: From the oldest non-deleted question, looks like the tag was created on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490942/saving-high-score-data) which doesn't show any hint about the possibility of a literal "datapersistance" class/object. Could be merged, though not sure about synonymizing them.